# Direct way to conditionally sum rows if condition is met in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a problem that's simple: I want to get the sum across some columns (`a` and `b` in my example) of strings equal to `-999`.

```
df = tibble(a = c('-999', 'b', '-999'),
           b = c('-999', 'a', 'b'),
           c = 1:3)
```

from this:

```
  a     b         c
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 -999  -999      1
2 b     a         2
3 -999  b         3
```

to this:

```
 a     b         c sum999
  <chr> <chr> <int>  <dbl>
1 -999  -999      1      2
2 b     a         2      0
3 -999  b         3      1
```

I managed to do it in a not so straightforward way:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(matches('^[ab]'), ~if_else(.x == '-999', 1, 0), 
                                        .names = '{.col}_' ) ) %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(sum999 = sum(c_across(matches('^[ab]_'))  ), 
                                        .keep = 'unused')
```

So, my question is, am I missing a better way to do this? Perhaps using `rowSums` ?

Thanks

Comment: OMG, I don't know half of this functions ;-) And I thought I knew tidyverse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two dplyr variants:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(sum999 = rowSums(select(., a:b) == "-999"))
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   a     b         c sum999
#   <chr> <chr> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 -999  -999      1      2
# 2 b     a         2      0
# 3 -999  b         3      1

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum999 = sum(c_across(a:b) == "-999")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

(I prefer the first since it's a bit more performant.)

Comment: Thanks! was very close to that solution but didn't try thel `select() == '-999'` route because it felt weird. Glad to know that works

Answer (score 1):

The old way:

```
df$sum999 <- rowSums(df[, c("a", "b")] == "-999")
```

If you make a comparison between a value and a 2D object like a matrix or a data frame, you get a matrix with logical values:

```
         a     b
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE
```

After that, you add the rows and get a vector of length `nrow(df)`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I could make comparisons with vectors, but not with matrices. Accepted the other answer because `dplyr` is my prefered way for work purposes